# pypi server, setup for automatically downloading packages from client?

Tags: linux, rhel, pip

I created a private pip storage and share it through `/var/www/html`, client configured a `pip.conf` file with trusted-host and index-url configuration, everything works fine when I'm downloading the packages manually to my private pip storage and run `pip install` from clients and the package exists..

The issue is that I want a client to run `pip install packageName` and if the package doesn't exist in my private pip storage it will download it automatically and store it there..

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you're looking for is called a pull through cache or pull through proxy.

#### pypicache

There's this project called [pypicache](https://pypicache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can do what you're asking for.

Excerpt:

> pypicache can be used in the following ways:
>
> 1. As a straight proxy to PyPI, caching package downloads where possible.
> 2. As a completely standalone PyPI server, useful for deploying from.
> 3. As an internal server for hosting custom packages.
>
> A possible day to day workflow could involve a pypicache server running on developer’s machines or in an office. Developers would install packages via this server. This server can also be shared by a deployment build tool which would install from the completely local copy of packages. This allows for repeatable builds.

#### Squid

If pypicache doesn't suite your needs, I've used [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) to setup a pull through proxy cache as well. That's likely going to be a bit more work but could be used in this scenario as well.

#### Using a proxy

Incidentally when you use a proxy cache like this, you'll need to invoke `pip` like so:

```
$ pip install --proxy=https://user@mydomain:port somepackage
```

**NOTE:** This can be configured into your environment so that you don't have to include `--proxy` for all your invocations.

```
$ export https_proxy=http://user@mydomain:port
$ pip install somepackage
```

#### References

- [Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: thanks for your response, I'm trying to use pypicache from there documentation install and i'm using pip install -e git+git@bitbucket.org:micktwomey/pypicache.git#egg=pypicache and getting an error: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Command "git clone -q git@bitbucket.org:micktwomey/pypicache.git /Volumes/Storage/Projects/pypichache/venv/src/pypicache" failed with error code 128 in None

Comment: @arikbi - I have no experience w/ that software, I use squid for something else.